# How to convert timestamp with milliseconds into datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I am using Google Drive API to download some files but unable to convert its datetime into Python datetime:

```
'2022-04-23T15:38:11.588Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

I thought this would work:

```
datetime.strptime(meta["modifiedTime"], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try this : `datetime.strptime('2022-04-23T15:38:11.588Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')`

Answer (score 1):

All but the final letter `Z` is isoformat, so we can just do:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = '2022-04-23T15:38:11.588Z'
print(datetime.fromisoformat(d[:-1]))
```

Output:

```
2022-04-23 15:38:11.588000
```

---

Alternative:

```
from dateutil.parser import isoparse

print(isoparse(d))

# Output:
2022-04-23 15:38:11.588000+00:00
```

Comment: This assumes the values are always UTC, right?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, which I believe is the case with any reply from Google API, but if there are doubts, I'd use my alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

Because the seconds you are getting from the Google Drive API time, is in float type format. So instead of just doing `%SZ`, you can specify `%S.%fZ` that will now read the seconds in float.

```
from datetime import datetime

date = '2022-04-23T15:38:11.588Z'
print(datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
```